# How to add web hook on specific build in TeamCity

Tags: api, rest, teamcity, webhooks

How to trigger build and add web hook on it via REST API? Or simply, how to add web hook on build by ID via API?
I viewed all the TC REST documentation but didn't find the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is documentation for triggering a build via REST API since TeamCity 8.1 [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-triggerBuild). Basically, you need to sent a POST request to `http://[server]/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue` with the build node as the content. There are build node examples in the documentation. If you're using an earlier version of TeamCity, you can trigger a build via script by following the instructions [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP#AccessingServerbyHTTP-TriggeringaBuildFromScript).

I haven't worked with it, but there's a plugin, tcWebHookTrigger, that you can use to make working with TeamCity's inbound API calls easier [here](https://github.com/tcplugins/tcWebHookTrigger) and it has documentation that should be able to get you started.

Comment: Hi. I am the author of the [tcWebHooks](https://github.com/tcplugins/tcWebHooks) plugin. tcWebHooks is for outbound (from TeamCIty) webhooks.

I found that the REST API is not very easy to integrate for inbound webhooks, so I have also just released a [WebHook Build Trigger](https://github.com/tcplugins/tcWebHookTrigger) plugin.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the heads up, will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @NetWolf Hi I downloaded the zip but when I try to upload it, it says, "Selected archive doesn't contain teamcity-plugin.xml file." Any idea why?

Comment: HI @redbottle. I double checked and I am using the 1.0.5 version from github but don't see this issue. Could I ask you to please post some more details on this ticket? https://github.com/tcplugins/tcWebHookTrigger/issues/8

Comment: @NetWolf I think it was to do with one of the zips which didn't have the correct team city agent xml element. I corrected the element to `teamcity-agent-plugin` and it worked. However I also found a zip that already had the correct element. Regardless do have a look

Comment: @redbottle That's strange. The plugin has no agent component, so should not need any agent references. The plugin only runs code on the server side. Regardless, I will do further testing to confirm. Thanks for pointing it out to me.